# when to normalize data with zscore (before or after split)

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was taking a udemy course, which made a strong case for normalizing only the train data (after the split from test data) since the model will typically used by fresh data, with features of the scale of the original set. And if you scale the test data, then you are not scoring the model properly.

On the other hand, what I found was that my two-class logistic regression model (created with Azure Machine Learning Studio) was getting terrible results after Z-Score scaling only the train data.

a. Is this a problem only with Azure's tools?
b. What is a good rule of thumb for when feature data needs to be scaled (one, two, or three orders of magnitude in difference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not scoring the model properly due to normalized test set doesn't seem to make sense:
you would presumably also normalize data that you use for predictions in the future.

I found [this similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27615/should-we-apply-normalization-to-test-data-as-well) in datascience stackexchange and the top answer suggests not only that test data has to be normalized, but you need to apply the exact same scaling as you have done to the training data, because the scale of your data is also taken into account by your model: differently scaled test/prediction data would potentially lead to over/under-exaggeration of a feature.

Comment: That was a good link. Seems like decision tree algorithms, don't need scaling. Which is a great find. Thanks from a newbie Data Scientist.

Comment: No worries from another newbie.